# What's with this bounding box in editing mode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

When presenting my UIImagePickerController with editing enabled, what does this bounding box mean during the edit phase?

[alt text http://www.irovr.com/stackOverflow/rect.jpg](http://www.irovr.com/stackOverflow/rect.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the cropping rectangle when you set the picker to editing mode. It's apparently not modifiable.